# Check when async javascript file is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I'd like to "bootstrap" my page only after all async files have been loaded.  Is there a way I can be notified when an async file has been loaded?

index.html

```
<script src="fileone.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<script src="filetwo.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you load them using javascript ? Appending this using JS allow you to use any event you wish

Answer (score 10):

Giving one of your scripts an ID...

```
<script src='fileone.js' type='text/javascript' async id='script_1'></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("script1").onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){ alert("Script loaded!"); }
</script>
```

Comment: How does monitoring one script assure the others are loaded as well?

Comment: You would do one of those "document.getElementById()" lines for each script, replacing the "script1" with the other script ID.